# Win32 Sleep() accuracy in game loop

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a basic fixed time-step game-loop that looks like

```
// somewhere in source...
f32 Win32_ElapsedSeconds(LARGE_INTEGER Start, LARGE_INTEGER End)
{
    f32 Result = ((f32)(End.QuadPart - Start.QuadPart)) / GlobalPerfCounterRate;
    return Result;
}

// Get the monitor refresh rate, etc... Let's assume 60Hz for simpler code.
f32 TargetFrameRate = 1.0f / 60.0f;
LARGE_INTEGER LastTimeCounter = Win32_GetCurrentCounter();

// Set the timer's resolution to be more accurate. We need 1ms at least!
UINT DesiredSchedulerMS = 1;
GlobalGranularSleeping = (timeBeginPeriod(DesiredSchedulerMS) == TIMERR_NOERROR);

LARGE_INTEGER PerfCountRate;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&PerfCountRate);
global f32 GlobalPerfCounterRate = PerfCountRate.QuadPart;

while (1)
{
    f32 ElapsedSeconds = Win32_ElapsedSeconds(LastTimeCounter, Win32_GetCurrentCounter());
    if (ElapsedSeconds < TargetFrameRate) {

#if 1
        if (GlobalGranularSleeping) {
            DWORD TimeMS = (DWORD) (1000.0f * (TargetFrameRate - ElapsedSeconds));
            if (TimeMS > 0) {
                Sleep(TimeMS);   
            }
        }
#endif

        f32 TestElapsedSeconds = Win32_ElapsedSeconds(LastTimeCounter, Win32_GetCurrentCounter());
        if (TestElapsedSeconds > TargetFrameRate)
        {
            DebugWrite("Oversleeping!\n");
        }

        while(ElapsedSeconds < TargetFrameRate) {
            // Remain idle until we hit the next frame
            ElapsedSeconds = Win32_ElapsedSeconds(LastTimeCounter, Win32_GetCurrentCounter());
        }

    } else {
        DebugWrite("Dropped frame!\n");
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER EndTimeCounter = Win32_GetCurrentCounter();
    s64 TimeCounterElapsed = EndTimeCounter.QuadPart - LastTimeCounter.QuadPart;        
    LastTimeCounter = Win32_GetCurrentCounter();

    f32 FPS = (f32)GlobalPerfCounterRate / TimeCounterElapsed;

    char Buff[10];
    sprintf(Buff, "%f\n", FPS);
    DebugWrite(Buff);
}
```

Output:

```
Oversleeping!
58.686577
Oversleeping!
58.927273
Oversleeping!
58.862743
Oversleeping!
58.702045
Oversleeping!
58.765110
Oversleeping!
58.619267
Oversleeping!
58.711994
Oversleeping!
58.787273
Oversleeping!
58.910568
59.998901
59.998901
Oversleeping!
58.464279
Oversleeping!
58.406231
Oversleeping!
58.685471
Oversleeping!
59.158722
Oversleeping!
58.601639
Oversleeping!
58.280674
Oversleeping!
58.634701
59.998901
59.998901
59.998901
Oversleeping!
59.125065
Oversleeping!
58.776192
Oversleeping!
```

The issue is that Sleep() is oversleeping sometimes, even though the granularity is set to 1ms (the assertion gets triggered).
So my question is even if windows guarantees that the granularity of Sleep is 1ms at least, is it possible for it to oversleep? Or is my code wrong...

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx): *"Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses."*

Comment: Windows is not a Real-Time OS, so all this granularity stuff is a _best-effort_ thing. That is, it will try to fall near the requested granularity, but it will not guarantee it. Moreover, you are asserting even if you are only 1 ms off!

Comment: As an aside, using `Sleep` in a game loop is rarely a good idea - it's better to just "do nothing" until the required time has elapsed

Comment: Yes... that is what I thought aswell. But   in a video series I am following (handmade hero), they assumed that if  timeBegin returned successfully, then it would be fine. And surprisingly enough, the code worked for them

Comment: @UnholySheep That was my initial thought, but for a 2d game I wanted to  minimize cpu usage

Comment: Maybe doing `if (TimeMS > 10) Sleep(TimeMS - 10);` could add some margin and work better?

Comment: @rodrigo that is my current solution :P But it feels like a hack doesn't it ?

Comment: @MattMatt2000: Well, yes, a bit hackish. You could also try raising the priority of the thread... anyway a few milliseconds up or down is expected and nothing to worry about.

Comment: You should be checking the display refresh rate, then using some kind of trigger based on that. Doesn't DirectX or the Windows API have a feature for this?

Comment: @rodrigo Messing around with thread priority is how you upset a lot of people. If everyone jammed at the highest level of priority nobody would ever get anything done.

Comment: @tadman I am already checking for the display refresh rate via GetDeviceCaps. I used 60hz here for simplicity

Comment: @tadman: Hey! I set all my processes to high priority ;-). Anyway, if you are playing a game, lagging because Windows is downloading whatever they fancy is not a good experience. High priority for the thread is ok, high priority for the background download is not.

Comment: @MattMatt2000 Getting the rate is good, but lining that up with VSync is also important. Some game engines don't use a fixed timer like this, but instead tell you how long it's been since the last frame buffer swap.

Comment: @rodrigo Interesting! I assume you're using SetThreadPriority ?

Comment: @rodrigo It's the other program's responsibility to set itself as low priority, not yours to force yourself high just because. The only apps that should be high priority are those that absolutely need it, like a real-time process where things will break if it's not able to intervene: Robotics and such. Try and play nice. Don't abuse your privileges.

Comment: @tadman I assume you mean variable timestep based engines? The problem is that the game is physics based, so if delta varies even a little, it may break stuff....

Comment: @MattMatt2000: `SetThreadPriority()` and `SetPriorityClass()` combined, maybe. But note that busy looping a real-time thread may hang your computer.

Comment: You can always pretend that the amount of time since the last frame was always the same for the purposes of having procedurally reproducible results. If you desync even a little you're right, the physics engine can and will behave wildly different which can cause chaos in multi-player games.

Comment: @MattMatt2000 If you want to combine fixed fixed-interval updates with event-driven presentation you will definitely need a multithreaded engine. If you need to sustain precise update intervals then you may even need to sacrifice one thread to loop querying timer non-stop. Though this typically can be avoided.

Comment: No. Don't mess with thread priority. That won't help at all.

Comment: When a sleep expires, the thread becomes available for scheduling.  That doesn't mean it will be scheduled immediately.  Also note that increasing the clock rate to 1 ms is really bad for battery life.  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even if windows guarantees that the granularity of Sleep is 1ms at
>   least

There is no such guarantee. Instead the actual time is rounded to nearest (ceil) system clock interval.

> If dwMilliseconds is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait
>   can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx)

Normally in games you do your stuff on animation frame events - either on explicit VSync events or "uncommitted WM_PAINT"s - WM_PAINT event handler that does not call `BeginPaint/EndPaint()` on Windows. All that depends on your platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am actually using Opengl/win32... do you know how I can render on explicit vsync events ?

Comment: You can use something  similar to `SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(-1)` or `SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);`. In this case SDL_GL_SwapWindow(w) in your game loop will wait until next VSync so your game loop will loop with VSync frequency. 

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval

Comment: ahh ok go it. wglSwapIntervalEXT in this case ;3